# javascript hover image and show left top to bottom right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a picture with 40Px 40Px when the cursor hovers over the image, then the image should be 100px 100px with, but to open slow left top to bottom right or right top to bottom left.When I move the cursor to the image back to its original position accurately 40px 40px.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to post proper questions. You'll find this right on the screen when you're composing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this without using CSS3 instead of javascript.

```css
.image-placeholder {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    transition: height 2s, width 2s;
}
.image-placeholder:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.images {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
.images li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-placeholder">
    <!-- You could also use the class on image tags -->
</div>

<!-- second example -->
<ul class="images">
    <li class="image-placeholder"></li>
    <li class="image-placeholder"></li>
    <li class="image-placeholder"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok I understand, but how do you top right to bottom left with javascript or jquery.When I have made class     for example:         $(".amazon").hover(function(){
        $(".amazon a img").toggleClass("amazon_hover");
                                                                                                                          CSS:     .amazon_hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
    -moz-transition:  height 2s, width 2s;    
    z-index: 10;
}

Comment: @Marko I don't see why you should do this with JQuery. I added a second example using `vertical-align: middle`. You could add your own variations using CSS.

Comment: I understand it does not matter whether css or javascript jquery important to me that we can open the image diagonally slowly top left to bottom right.              thanks in advance

Comment: but these solutions which sent me open image horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS transition:

```
img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    transition: all 2s;
}
img:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And ofcourse a [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ocLkvb73/)

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you can use just CSS3 to accomplish this, but if you want the "boxes" to stay in place as you are hovering, then you can also use a negative margin.

For your example, you start with 40 pixels, expand to 100 pixels. That leaves you a 60 pixel difference, which you then split in half (half for each side of the box), which gives you a negative margin of 30 pixels.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```